# do Members of the class can only be accessed indirectly via set and get-methods?

Tags: c++, class, private

i know that Members of the class can only be accessed indirectly via set and get-methods. What is the output of the following C++ program? Why is this possible? could someone Explain to me why this is a bad programming style?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Test
{
private:
    int N;
public:
    void setN(int N_in) { N = N_in; };
    int getN(){ return N; };
    int* getptrN(){ return &N; };
};

int main()
{
    Test A;
    A.setN(5);
    int* ptr = A.getptrN();
    cout << A.getN() << endl;
    *ptr = 10;
    cout << ptr << endl;
    cout << A.getN() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like homework.

Comment: u clever =) and u won't help?.. i have more to ask!

Comment: Providing a method that returns a pointer to a member circumvents encapsulation. As such, it's a bad idea since you can't guarantee that the object is in a defined state.

Comment: *"What is the output of the following C++ program?"* haven't you even run it to find out?  Even if you don't have a compiler on your PC/device, you can cut and paste the code into an online compiler (e.g. ideone.com).

Answer (score 0):

The `public`, `protected`, and `private` access specifiers apply to names of members. They let you specify which data and functions are available to users of a class *by name*. If at runtime you grant access to a variable or function through some other means, such as by pointer or reference, then the compile-time access specifiers are no longer at play.

The basic idea of encapsulation is that you want objects to represent values in the problem you’re trying to solve, and you want those values to always be meaningful. You restrict which states an object can have, so that the object can only ever represent *meaningful* states.

For example, it’s not meaningful for a length to be negative, so a hypothetical `setLength` member function should never succeed when given a negative argument value.

By granting unrestricted access to a member of an object, you allow it to be modified in ways that don’t necessarily produce a valid state, which can make your program behave incorrectly. If `x` assumes that its length will only ever be non-negative, but you say `*x.getPtrLength() = -1;`, then all bets are off.

Answer (score 0):

The `public` , `private` try to bring the concept of encapsulation to our codes. This concept helps to separate what that is happening inside of a class to the outside world. This does NOT mean that you can't access to memory space of your objects. Because you have created an instance of the Test object you can access to it; you just need the address of inside variables (which you have provided by `return &N`).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure I completely understand what you're asking (what exactly is the problem you see with the code), but you need to refresh your memory on `public:` and `private:`.